# RDS Session host server disconnecting all user profile disks intermittently

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, user-profile-disks

I have a Windows RDS solution utilizing user profile disks which are stored on a file server.

There are two session host servers which the RDS Gateway loadbalances between.

I'm seeing an issue whereby at certain points in the day, all of the user profile disks which are mounted on a specific session host server become disconnected. The result of which is that icons on the taskbar all drop off, browsing in file explorer hangs and crashes.

[image]

Looking at the event log, I can see lots of event ID 129's firing off at the time of the issue with...

> Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort1, was issued

I did a bit of a google and found some posts suggesting that having 'balanced power mode' selected in the power settings will cause this issue.
I checked and, sure enough, the servers were set to balanced mode. I've changed this to high performance.

Are there any other reasons this might occur that anyone has come across?

If the power setting option is really the answer, what might have led to this changing? as this issue has only just occured yet the servers have been in production for almost 24 months without issue and none of the admin team have changed it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your RAID controller. Any logs from the raid controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Microsoft's recent KB4467684 update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4467684/windows-10-update-kb4467684

On paper it should address two relevant issues that we are seeing:

1) Addresses an issue that causes File Explorer to stop working during logoff.

2) Addresses an issue that slows server performance or causes the server to stop responding because of numerous Windows firewall rules. To enable the changes, add a new registry key “DeleteUserAppContainersOnLogoff” (DWORD) on “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy” using Regedit, and set it to 1.

Don't forget to set the associated registry key. We are installing the update tonight and hope for positive results tomorrow.